# How to calculate the number of subgroups of a group whose order is $19$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to calculate the number of subgroups of a group whose order is $19$?

Normally, I'd resolve this problem with the Lagrange's Theorem, but I don't know how to do it with this one because I only know the order.

So this is not the best approach.

What's the answer to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean that the subgroups have order $19$ or the main group has order $19$?

Comment: Hint: There's only one group of order $19$.

Comment: The main group has order 19.

Comment: How many divisors does 19 have? :P

Comment: @dem0nakos I'm definitely missing something. If the group has the order 19, doesn't that mean it has any 19 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach with Lagrange's Theorem is a correct one. Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| = 19$ and $H \le G$. Then, By Lagrange's Theorem, we have $|H|\  \big |\ |G| = 19$. But $19$ is a prime number so only divisors of $19$ are $1$ and $19$. If $|H| = 1$, then clearly $H$ is trivial group. If $|H| = 19$, then $H = G$.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If the main group has order $19$, which is a prime, then it can only be the cyclic $\mathbb Z_{19}$. Its only subgroups are the trivial group and itself.

Comment: Why is it Z_19? I don't really understand. If the group's order is 19, that means it has 19 elements. Can it not be any 19 elements put together?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu Because it is a _prime number_.

Comment: The order of each element should divide 19, so every element has order 1 or 19 and only the identity element has order 1. So if you pick one of the non identity elements, $g$, in the group you must have $g,g^2,g^3,...,g^{18},g^{19}=id$ and thats 19 elements and it is also $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel got it. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @OctavianNicolescu, the map $\Bbb Z_p \to \{g^i, i=0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, defined by $m\mapsto g^m$, is an isomorphism, so the two groups "are the same".

Answer (score 1):

Let $H\leq G$ be a subgroup of $G$. From Lagrange's Theorem $|H|\mid |G|$. Since $|G|=19$ we have that either $|H|=1$ or $|H|=19$. Let's consider both cases:

- $|H|=1$. In this case the subgroup $H$ has only one element. Every group has to have an identity element, so $H=\langle e\rangle$.
- $|H|=19$. Let's see what this group looks like. Let $g\in H$, the order of $g$, $|g|$, divides $|H|$, so $|g|\mid 19$. Only on element has order $1$, which is the identity. If $g\neq e$, then $|g|=19$ which means that $g$ is a generator, $H=\langle g\rangle$. Thus we can make an isomorphism $$\phi: H\rightarrow\Bbb Z_{19}\\g\mapsto 1$$